# add nodes to google Organizational Chart

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

i create organization chart page usnig google Organizational Chart, as shown in this screenshot
[image]

after writing node description and selecting  parent node from drop down list, i want to add the node to the chart,and refresh the chart again, to contain the new node.
what is the best way to this?
thank you